# Image inserted via Macro is moving when clicking in to another cell

Tags: excel, vba

Please note that while I am quite proficient in Excel, I have almost no knowledge of VBA and Macros. A friend wrote this code for me, but it doesn't work exactly as I need, so am looking for help.

I have a Macro that pulls the file path of an image and inserts the image into a cell when the data in a cell is changed.

The data being changed is in cell C3, which changes the image file path, which is stored in I2, and the image should be displayed in cell I4, which is the top left most cell of a larger merged cell.

There is also a bit of code that deletes the old image when changing information so it doesn't keep adding an image on top of the old image.

Everything works fine apart from when clicking into any cell to edit the data, once I click out, the image moves to where clicked out. I just need the image to stay in I4

Here is the current code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ProdCell As Range
Dim PicPath As String, Pic As Picture, ImageCell As Range

Set ProdCell = Range("C3")

If Not Application.Intersect(ProdCell, Range("C3")) _
    Is Nothing Then

    Shapes(1).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    PicPath = Range("I2").Value
    Set ImageCell = Range("I4").MergeArea

    Set Pic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PicPath)
    With Pic
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Left = ImageCell.Left
        .Top = ImageCell.Top
        .Width = ImageCell.Width
        .Height = ImageCell.Height
    End With
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: That `If` line is pointless. C3 is always going to intersect with C3. Try replacing `Prodcell` with `Target`.

Comment: Not that I'm sure why the picture moves in any case.

Comment: That solved a part of the problem. the image would move whenever I interacted with any cell, but it only moves when I interact with cell C3 now.